# Cluto sparse matrix clustering

Tags: data-mining, cluster-analysis, cluto

I downloaded cluto and I want to send a text file includes sparse data as input and want to get the output of clustered data. For example:

```
4   3   9
1 0.4   2 0.4
1 0.4   2 0.4
2 1.2   3 1.2
1 0.4   2 0.4   3 0.4
```

is my input and ı want to get the output as

```
column  cluster
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       1
```

I cannot find the way of that. How can I use cluto vcluster.exe to achieve this process?

Answer (score 1):

"vcluster" has an option to specify the file of cluster assignments named "-clustfile".
The statistics will be shown to the standard io, and the clustering result will be written to the file.

In the file, there will be lines of single number, representing the cluster id of the specific row. In your case, the file will look like:

```
1
1
2
1
```